# If $a+b+c$, $a^2+b^2+c^2$, $a^3+b^3+c^3$ are real, then so are a,b,c

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials

> Let $a,b,c$ be complex numbers with distinct magnitudes such that $a+b+c$, $a^2+b^2+c^2$, $a^3+b^3+c^3$ are real.
>
> Prove that $a,b,c$ are real numbers as well.

I tried to go for contradiction: WLOG assume $a$ is not real. Since $a+b+c\in \mathbb R$, at least one of the numbers $b$ or $c$ is not real. WLOG $b$ is not real. I couldn't get any contradiction from that.

I also attempted something using elementary symmetric polynomials: let $s=a+b+c$, $q=ab+ac+bc$ and $p=abc$

Since $a^2+b^2+c^2=s^2-2q$, $\;\;q$ is real as well.

Since $a^3+b^3+c^3=s^3-3qs+3p$, $\;\;p$ is real.

What then?

Source: an oral exam at a French engineering school.

Comment: You tagged this as [tag:contest-math], meaning it is from a contest - which one?

Comment: @barto Oral exam at a French engineering school.

Comment: Is this true? What about 1, $i$, and$ -i$? $a+b+c = 1+i-i = 1, a^2+b^2+c^2 = 1+(-1)+(-1) = -1, a^3+b^3+c^3 = 1+(-i)+i = 1,$ but they're not real.

Comment: @LinusS. You should have read more carefully. $a$,$b$ and $c$ have distinct magnitudes. In your counterexample, $|i|=|-i|=1$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: As you've shown, $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ has real coefficients. What can be said about the complex roots of a polynomial with real coefficients?

A more geometric proof would be to first show that if any of $a,b,c$ are real, we can replace that value with any real value and it is still true, so you can assume that $|a|<|b|<|c|=1$ and $c$ is *not* real, by scaling and replacing any real values with smaller values.

But we can prove inductively (using your realization that $p,q$ are real) that $a^n+b^n+c^n$ is always real. Then pick $N$ so that $|a|^n+|b|^n<\epsilon$ for $n>N$. Then the imaginary part of $c^n$ would have to be less than $\epsilon$ for *all* $n>N$. Then show this is impossible for a particular $\epsilon$ unless $c$ is real.

Comment: Of course! How could I miss that !

Comment: This problem would have been much more obvious if it had stated the stronger result - that if $a+b+c,a^2+b^2+c^2,a^3+b^3+c^3$ are all real, then one of $a,b,c$ must be real and the other two must be either real or conjugates of each other.